# how to install windows 7 if its not compatible with the hardware

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Is it possible that a laptop or a computer isn't compatible with windows 7 even if it has 2GB of memory and a decent 2GHz intel processor?

Its a Dell laptop with drivers that is only compatible with Vista.

What are the reasons for this incompatibility?
Specifically incompatible in WLAN Card.
What can I do to make it compatible.?

Comment: What is the model number of the Dell laptop and which WLAN card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is it possible that a laptop or a computer isn't compatible with windows 7 even if it has 2Gb of memory and a decent 2Ghz intel processor and the hard drive has 200Gb free space?`

It is not the hardware specs that are causing the problem. Just because a computer/laptop meets certain hardware requirements does not mean it will support an operating system.

`What are the reasons for this incompatibility?Specifically incompatible in WLAN Card. What can I do to make it compatible.?`

**Drivers** are what affect compatibility. You will need to make sure you have Windows 7 drivers for all the components that require drivers. Windows 7 has very good driver support but you may need to obtain Windows 7 drivers directly from the PC maker (Dell in this case) or from manufacturers of the internal components. As @Sim has also pointed out, you may be able to use Vista drivers if you cannot find Windows 7 drivers.

Also, depending on whether you're using a 32 bit (x86) or 64 bit (x64) version of Windows 7 you will need to find 32 bit or 64 bit drivers.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know why <unknown WLAN card> doesn't work with Windows 7. Probably drivers. See if the manufacturer has an updated driver for it.

You should still be able to install it, you just won't be able to use said piece of equipment without the correct driver.

Comment: Further to this try the Vista drivers as they will most likely just work with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops should work with windows 7 provides that you have the vista driver with the correct bitness (I.e. 32 or 64 bit)

just provide the vista driver if you are asked. If it happens that you so not see the dialog asking for the drivers then go to device manager . Right click my computer / properties / you should see device manager.

Good luck!